# SQL Server 2012 temp table OBJECT_ID issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, temp-tables

We have an issue upgrading to SQL Server 2012. I am using the following script to create temporary tables that used to work fine on SQL Server 2008 R2 but now it is generating an error with 2012:

```
if (OBJECT_ID( 'tempdb..#idstable') > 0)
    truncate table #idstable
else
    create table #idstable (id int not null)
```

the error thrown is

> There is already an object named '#idstable' in the database.

This is obviously not thrown the first time I use the script (in the same transaction).

Any idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012, #temp tables are created with a negative `object_id`, so your script won't work as is. The safest way is:

```
IF OBJECT_ID( 'tempdb..#idstable') IS NOT NULL
```

([I blogged about this here, and knew it would catch someone](https://sqlblog.org/2010/11/09/sql-server-v-next-denali-breaking-change-to-temp-tables).)

Though your script is bound for failure anyway, if it is part of a single batch. The parser will not let you try and create the same #temp table twice.

Comment: I just cant thing of a good reason why Microsoft is always changing things like this... Thanks Man!

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou they can change anything that's undocumented. Has Microsoft ever told you that #temp table object_ids are always positive? This is a problem of relying on something you've merely observed...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'tempdb..#idstable', N'U') IS NOT NULL
    truncate table #idstable
else
    create table #idstable (id int not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

My dears,

This issue is due to the truncate statement. Truncate is used to delete all records preserving the table. Use drop table instead of truncate table and this will works fine ;-)

Comment: That is so untrue, because I need to only truncate the table if it exist otherwise create it so at the end you are sure you have an empty temp table.